# Operator for parametrized struct is dependant on another operator

Tags: operator-overloading, rust, multiplication

I'm writing LoG filter in Rust and I wanted to use `|` as operator for element wide multiplication operator (`a_{i,j} * b_{i,j}`), but compilator is complaining about `Output` result. It say that `self[(i, j)] * out[(i, j)]` does not equal `Mul<N>::Output`.

```
impl<N> BitOr<Matrix<N>> for Matrix<N> where N: Mul<N> {
    type Output = Matrix<N>;

    fn bitor(self, other: Matrix<N>) -> Matrix<N> {
        if self.width() != other.width() ||
            self.height() != other.height() {
                panic!("Matrices need to have equal dimensions");
            }

        let mut out = Matrix::new(self.width(), self.height());

        for i in 0..(self.width()) {
            for j in 0..(self.height()) {
                out[(i, j)] = self[(i, j)] * out[(i, j)];
            }
        }

        out
    }
}
```

Is there any way to set output based on `Mul<N>::Output` type?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess this should work:

```
impl<N> BitOr<Matrix<N>> for Matrix<N> where N: Mul<N> {
    type Output = Matrix<<N as Mul<N>>::Output>;

    fn bitor(self, other: Matrix<N>) -> Matrix<<N as Mul<N>>::Output> {
        if self.width() != other.width() ||
            self.height() != other.height() {
                panic!("Matrices need to have equal dimensions");
            }

        let mut out = Matrix::new(self.width(), self.height());

        for i in 0..(self.width()) {
            for j in 0..(self.height()) {
                out[(i, j)] = self[(i, j)] * out[(i, j)];
            }
        }

        out
    }
}
```

Comment: BTW, maybe even `N::Output` instead of `<N as Mul<N>>::Output` would work, but I'm not sure here.

Answer (score 1):

You didn't provide a small runnable example, so I made my own. This works:

```
use std::ops::{Mul,BitOr};

#[derive(Copy,Show)]
struct Matrix<N>(N, N);

impl<N> BitOr<Matrix<N>> for Matrix<N> where N: Mul<N, Output=N> {
    type Output = Matrix<N>;

    fn bitor(self, other: Matrix<N>) -> Matrix<N> {
        Matrix(self.0 * other.0, self.1 * other.1)
    }
}

fn main() {
    let a = Matrix(-1,-1);
    let b = Matrix(2,3);
    let c = a | b;

    println!("{:?}", c)
}
```

The main thing I had to do was `N: Mul<N, Output=N>`, which specifies that `N` must be multipliable by another `N` *and* will result in another `N`.

Comment: FWIW, this approach limits the implementation only to those types whose multiplication operation returns themselves (i.e. `Output=N`). This is not always desirable.